# How to page while maintaining the querystring values in ASP.Net Mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, pagination

I am using the pager provided by [Martijn Boland](http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2010/01/27/paging-demo-for-asp-net-mvc-2/) to implementing paging in my Asp.Net Mvc 2 application.

My form uses the GET method to send all parameters to the querystring, it is a search form with several form elements.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("SearchResults", "Search", FormMethod.Get))
       {%>
```

On the SearchResults View I am trying to implement paging:

```
<div class="pager">
    <%= Html.Pager(Model.PageSize, Model.PageNumber, Model.TotalItemCount, 
        new { Request.QueryString })%>
</div>
```

The Html.Pager has some overloads which I am not too clear on how to use. The Request.QueryString makes the querystring look like this:

```
http://localhost:1155/Search/SearchResults?QueryString=Distance%3D10%26txtZip%3D%26cb&page=2
```

Should it not be like this?

```
http://localhost:1155/Search/SearchResults?Distance=20&txtZip=10021&page=2
```

Comment: I have listed two of querystring parameters, there are several more and I am trying to avoid listing them separately.

Comment: Did you see my edit, you have to cast the QueryString into a IDictionnary and the pass it to ne RouteValueDictionnary constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my guess would be to write your pager like this

```
<%= Html.Pager(Model.PageSize, Model.PageNumber, Model.TotalItemCount,  new { Distance = Request["Distance"], txtZip = Request["txtZip"] })%>
```

but it's only a guess, i've never used that...

**Edit:** see [ASP.Net MVC Keeping action parameters between postbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122104/asp-net-mvc-keeping-action-parameters-between-postbacks)
so you have to create a `RouteValueDictionary` from the QueryString which is a `NameValueCollection`.

Comment: There are more than two parameters, so I am trying to avoid listing them separately.

Comment: I'd like so second this answer (the Edit: part). Create a helper function to convert querystring params to a RouteValueDictionary and feed that to the Pager. Maybe ASP.NET MVC already contains such a function?