# How do I keep the routevalues when going from page to page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have a URL that is: `http://localhost:3018/TestEdit/Index/5/100100/44`. But when I click on the link to another page I get this: `http://localhost:3018/AnotherPage`. I would like it automagically to be this: `http://localhost:3018/AnotherPage/Index/5/100100/44`. Is there anyway for the Routing system to handle this? Or do I have to explicitly pass the routevalues through the ActionLinks? (That's how I'm doing it now.)

In short, example of best practice (if there is one), please?

Comment: I'm going to accept @rouen answer as the answer. Since it led me to the actual answer, since it seems [someone had the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779932/mvc-actionlink-add-all-optional-paramters-from-current-url). So this is one of the rare times, where I'll say "this is a duplicate". :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider creating your own ActionLink extension method to do this - just take current route data from context and call default ActionLink with it.. 3 lines of code, and save you many dirty stuff in views.

Comment: Since you're generally correct and someone on SO had the same problem, I guess you don't have to provide an example anymore.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way. You'll have to pass them manually.